# grails 2.0 hangs in IntelliJ when clicking Run button

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I've been using Grails 1.3.7, but brought down 2.0 for a new project.  IntelliJ indicates it handles both versions at the same time ... you choose the version when you set up the project.  However, when I go to run this new project (click green arrow, or do a 'run-app' using the grails command window in Intellij), it puts out the following (below) and simply hangs.  This is the case if I answer "y" or "n", to its question.   Any thoughts?

Thanks, Ray

---

| Loading Grails 2.0.0.RC1
| Configuring classpath

> ####################################################.
>
> Grails would like to send information to VMware domains to improve your experience. We include anonymous usage information as part of these downloads.

The Grails team gathers anonymous usage information to improve your Grails experience, not for marketing purposes. The information is used to discover which Grails plugins are most popular and is published on the plugin portal.

We also use this information to help guide our roadmap, prioritizing the features and Grails plugins most valued by the community and enabling us to optimize the compatibility of technologies frequently used together.

Please see the Grails User Agent Analysis (UAA) Terms of Use at http://www.springsource.org/uaa/terms_of_use for more information on what information is collected and how such information is used. There is also an FAQ at http://www.springsource.org/uaa/faq for your convenience.

To consent to the Terms of Use, please enter 'Y'. Enter 'N' to indicate your do not consent and anonymous data collection will remain disabled.

####################################################.

Enter Y or N:[y,n] y

Comment: Run it on the command line, answer the question, and it shouldn't ask you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be occurs this bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-73228
Try to use latest version of IDEA: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11+EAP
It's recommended to use IDEA 11 to work with Grails 2.0.0 because IDEA 10 doesn't support some features from Grails 2.0.0 (e.g. definition actions via methods in controllers)