# grails upgrade command from 1.3.7 to 2.0.0

Tags: grails

I am trying to perform a grails upgrade. However it seems to get stacked and does not deliver any errors or any reason about why is not finishing

```
grails upgrade

| Loading Grails 2.0.0
| Configuring classpath
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development
| Environment set to development.
| Environment set to development..
| Environment set to development...
| Environment set to development....
| Environment set to development.....
| NOTE: Your application currently expects grails version [1.3.7], this target w                                            ill upgrade it to Grails 2.0.0
>
        WARNING: This target will upgrade an older Grails application to 2.0.0.
        Are you sure you want to continue?
                   [y,n] y
```

Comment: It seems an issue of the IDE. I was using Intellj 10.5. With grails new command line opened in a normal windows prompt, it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ 10.5 does not support Grails 2.0.

You'll need to upgrade to IntelliJ 11 to get support for Grails 2.0, which would have fixed that bug.

More info: [YouTrack Bug #73228](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-73228)

This is also listed here already: [grails 2.0 hangs in IntelliJ when clicking Run button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864467/grails-2-0-hangs-in-intellij-when-clicking-run-button)